# Linear systems of equations with arrow and shaded triangle in row echelon form

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, equations, tikz-arrows

I would like to create a handout for my students on the Gauss algorithm. I'm done with it so far, except for one small thing. In each step I would like to use the arrows to indicate which calculation has just been carried out. At the end of the algorithm I want to emphasize the triangular shape. It should look something like this:

[image]

Here is a code snippet

```
\documentclass[DIN, pagenumber=false, fontsize=11pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{16cm}{p{1.2cm}|X|X}
\textbf{Schritt} & \textbf{Ausf\"uhrliche Schreibweise} & \textbf{Matrixschreibweise} \\
\hline
1 & \[ \sysdelim| |
\systeme{%
   x + 2y +3z = 17,
   2x - 3y + 2z = 4,
    3x -5y + 4z = 9\,} \] & \[ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 17 \\ 2 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & -5 & 4 & 9 \end{pmatrix} \] \\
\hline
2 & \[ \sysdelim| |
\systeme{%
   x + 2y +3z = 17,
   -7y - 4z = -30,
     -11y - 5z = -42\,} \] & \[ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 17 \\ 0 & -7 & -4 & -30 \\ 0 & -11 & -5 & -42 \end{pmatrix} \] \\
\hline
3 & \[ \sysdelim| |
\systeme{%
   x + 2y +3z = 17,
   -7y - 4z = -30,
     9z = 36\,} \] & \[ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 17 \\ 0 & -7 & -4 & -30 \\ 0 & 0 & 9 & 36 \end{pmatrix} \]
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, can you put a minimal complete example and not a snippet code? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Done!

Comment: Have you seen the package witharrows? There is something. https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/witharrows/witharrows.pdf

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank for the information. But how can I achieve the shaded triangle?

Comment: Using pure tikz.

Comment: @wayne `witharrows` uses `TikZ`. It is easy to customize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution, using `tabularray` package and `tikzmark`Ti*k*Z library could be:

```tex
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage    {lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage    {tabularray}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset
{% styles
   plus/.style={midway,right,yshift=#1},
   my arrow/.style={-latex,thick,line cap=round,line join=round,shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.2em}
}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{006600}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\caption{with \texttt{tabularray} \& \texttt{tikzmark}.}
\[\begin{tblr}
{% format
   colspec  ={rrll},
   row{4,7} ={abovesep=3ex},
   row{5}   ={fg=teal},
   row{6}   ={fg=magenta},
   row{9}   ={fg=mygreen},
   column{1}={rightsep=0.2em},
   column{2}={leftsep=0em},
   column{4}={leftsep=3em}
}% content
                  x+2y+3z = &                  17 & \tikzmarknode{b1}{\cdot(-2)} 
                                                  & \tikzmarknode{c1}{\cdot(-3)}\\
                 2x-3y+2z = & \tikzmarknode{b2}{4}\\
                 3x-5y+4z = & \tikzmarknode{b3}{9}\\
                  x+2y+3z = &                  17\\
                   -7y-4z = &                 -30 & \tikzmarknode{b5}{\cdot(-11)}\\
                  -11y-5z = &                 -42 & \tikzmarknode{b6}{\cdot7}\\
\tikzmarknode{a7}{x+2y+3z}= &                  17\\
                   -7y-4z = &                 -30\\
     \tikzmarknode{a9}{9z}= &                  36
\end{tblr}\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[teal   ,my arrow] (b1.east) --++ (2em,0) |- node[teal   ,plus=2ex] {$+$} (b2);
\draw[magenta,my arrow] (c1.east) --++ (2em,0) |- node[magenta,plus=4ex] {$+$} (b3);
\draw[mygreen,my arrow] (b5.east) --++ (2em,0) |- node[mygreen,plus=2ex] {$+$} (b6);
\fill[orange,rounded corners=0.4cm,opacity=0.4]
    ([shift={(-2em,0.8ex)}]a7.north west) -| ([shift={(0.2em,-2.8ex)}]a9.south east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [at]JuanCastano - Many thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering the shaded triangle question because Sebastiano's comment already answered the other one:

You can use the Tikz package, you can place this stub inside your tabbular.

```
% \usepackage{tikz} % <--- add to preambule
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate  (x1)at (-3.2,-0.5) ;
\coordinate  (x2)at (-3.2,2) ;
\coordinate  (x3)at (-6.5,2) ;
\fill[color=yellow,opacity = 0.3] (x1) -- (x2) --(x3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you aren't familiar with tikz, you may not understand much of what I wrote here.

[tikz doc](https://tikz.dev/)

Comment: First of all Thank you! But how can i shift the triangle to overlap over my system?

Comment: To make it simple, the 3 coordinates x1, x2 and x3 define an area that is filled by yellow colour. To change what you colour, all you need is to "move" x1, x2 or/and x3. aka change the coordinate `(-3.2,-0.5)`, any coordinate to anything you like. I really recommand you to get introduce to tikz if you want to go further.

Comment: [at]anis - I'll read this through carefully. I'm still relatively new to teaching myself latex. Many thanks for your hints